# Series and Parallel Capacitors in Circuit Analysis

Tags: circuit-analysis, capacitor, parallel, series

In the circuit below:
[image]

I performed my calculations considering:
$$\frac1{C_{eq}}=\sum_{k=1}^N C_k^{-1},$$
and
$$C_{eq}=\sum_{k=1}^N C_k,$$
when the capacitors are in series and when they are in parallel, respectively.

Doing from the rightmost to the leftmost loops, I got the following equivalent capacitances:

1. Three capacitors (6\$\mu F\$, 6\$\mu F\$, 6\$\mu F\$) in series: 2\$\mu F\$
2. The above result in parallel with the 2\$\mu F\$ capacitor: 4\$\mu F\$
3. The above result in series with the 4\$\mu F\$ capacitor: 2\$\mu F\$
4. The above result in parallel with capacitor 8\$\mu F\$: 10\$\mu F\$
5. The 5 and 10 muF capacitors in series: 10/3 \$\mu F\$
6. The last two results in parallel: 40/3 \$\mu F\$
7. The previous result in series with 6\$\mu F\$ and \$\mu F\$: 1.73 \$\mu F\$;

In my answer sheet the answer is 1.67 \$\mu F\$.

I can't see where I went wrong.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This is what you have after step 4:

[image]

5. Two \$10 \mu F\$ capacitors in series: \$5 \mu F\$
6. Two \$5 \mu F\$ capacitors in parallel: \$10 \mu F\$
7. The previous result in series with \$6 \mu F\$ and \$3 \mu F\$: \$1.67 \mu F\$;